# Is this a a mistake in proof of ergodic theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

[Check picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57M09.jpg)

I don't understand the final formula. Birkhoff's theorem says that the sample mean of some random variable taken on a map $T^{i - 1}$ (index is $i$ in the sum, from 1 to $n$) (ergodic and measure preserving) approaches almost surely the mean of $X$. However, in the proof, there is no map $T$ at all, just that one random variable? The sum has index $i$, yet there is no $i$ being summed over, only one random variable independent of $i$?

In the proof, $\hat{X}_1$ is the first coordinate projection, $P$ is our probability measure, and $\mathbb{X}(P)$ is the distribution of a process $(X_n)$ on a measurable space of infinite sequences and an associated sigma algebra generataed by the coordinate projections.

Comment: The map $T$ is the shift on coordinates of the vector $(X_n)$.  In any case, I would look for a source which is a little more careful.  The writing in the excerpt you linked is a bit of a mess.

Comment: Taking a second look at the final formula... find a better text.

Comment: Ah yes. So if the shift map is stationary and ergodic (which it is per assumption since $X_n$ is stat and ergodic), then the proof makes sense. But I don't see the shift map anywhere... is it like implied in some way?